# Lightswitch HTML Client stuck at splash screen

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I made a fairly simple Lightswitch HTML Client App and when I try to debug it it stays stuck at the initial splash/loading screen:

[image]

I took a look at the trace.axd and it looks like everything is going good up until it's time for the queries to start being retrieved. No requests are being sent to the service.

I have verified that the ApplicationData.svc service is working correctly.

I cannot set a breakpoint in the default.aspx so how can I find out what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was, look for errors in IE the Developer Tools / Console output. It pointed me to a  script block in the default.aspx page which contained invalid javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced all the scripts folder content with upated files, and updated the references to them in default.html:

I don't know which was the problema file, but now it Works!